Firebase Auth login with Twitter stop working on iOS app
Steps to reproduce:

Click button Login With Twitter from my app
A browser opened Twitter login page
Input username and password to Twitter login page
Click Authorize App
Expected login success then open my app. But it went to Twitter app and nothing happened then.

Follow guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login
provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
  if error != nil {
    // Handle error.
  }
  if credential != nil {
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in

    }
  }
}

